# Combine array of dates and sum values per month in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

i've got an array of dates as keys and values (integers) in the form:

```
[2015-07-14] => 40
[2015-07-15] => 5
[2015-07-16] => 8
[2015-07-17] => 0
[2015-07-18] => 0
[2015-07-19] => 0
[2015-07-20] => 0
[2015-07-21] => 0
[2015-07-22] => 0
[2015-07-23] => 0
[2015-07-24] => 0
[2015-07-25] => 0
[2015-07-26] => 0
[2015-07-27] => 0
[2015-07-28] => 0
[2015-07-29] => 0
[2015-07-30] => 0
[2015-07-31] => 0
[2015-08-01] => 0
[2015-08-02] => 1
[2015-08-03] => 1
[2015-08-04] => 2
[2015-08-05] => 1
```

The startdate and enddate can be selected by the user.

Is there a quick and easy way to combine those dates and sum the values as per month? In my example, the result should look somethine like:

```
[2015-07] => 53
[2015-08] => 5
```

The way that I tried to solve that was to use explode functions and then try to recombine those, but that seems to me a bit more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We need to see what you've tried to tell you if it works; but the answer is likely to be subjective and as such this question is likely to be flagged for closure.

Comment: So quick question, if I was to select the starting point from `2015-07-22` to `2015-07-31` will I get a result of 0? Or will the days before `2015-07-22` count as days in the month, even though I haven't selected that day? Or better question can a user select days too or just months?

Comment: A combination of array_map and array_sum would be a solution

Comment: People answering with `substr` I just wanna point out it's a really bad idea as date formatting may change in the future. You'd want to stick with the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/ro/class.datetime.php) for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

```
foreach($yourarray as $key=>$val){
   $result[substr($key,0,7)] += $val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works like a charm.  I knew there was an easier way than using explode("-",...) :-)

Comment: Note that this will throw E_NOTICE errors if they are turned on (and they should).

Comment: yes, it will throw notice, you can use `@` to ignore it or just simply define each one, but PHP can easily handle theese ones,  it wont harm your code read this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132410/php-shorthand-addition-operator-undefined-offset its bad practice only because it would kill your code in another language but NOT in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is.

```
$per_month = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
  $month = substr($key, 0, 7);
  if (!isset($per_month[$month])) {
    $per_month[$month] = 0;
  }
  $per_month[$month] += $val;
}
echo var_dump($per_month["2015-07"]);
```

Edit:

Also, instead of substr() you could use sscanf()

```
foreach...
list($y, $m, $d) = sscanf($key, "%d-%d-%d");
$per_month[$y.'-'.$m] += $val;
endforeach
```

... or explode()

```
foreach...
$var = explode('-', $key); // $var[0] = year, $var[1] = month ...
...
$per_month[$var[0].'-'.$var[1]] += $val;
endforeach
```

There are probably many more ways, these are just off the top of my head

Comment: Thank you Alex, I was using the explode-function befor, but I thought this makes things more complicated than they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

For me substr() method didn't worked in Laravel.

So I tried it differently instead of substr() method.

```
$monthwise_data = array();
foreach($datewise_data as $key => $value){
    $month_key = date('Y-m', strtotime($key));
    if(array_key_exists($month_key, $monthwise_data)){
        // If we've already added this month to the new array, add the value
        $monthwise_data[$month_key] += $value;
    }
    else{
        // Otherwise create a new element with month as key and store the value
        $monthwise_data[$month_key] = $value;
    }
}
dd($monthwise_data);
```